# Trouble to compare two dictionnaries with a tkinter/python code

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, comparison

I'm looking to compare my good_answer dictionnary with my resultat dictionnary. My project is to generate items randomly except one who is associated with the picture also choose randomly. The problem is that I can't compare the user answer with the rigth one.

I tried multiple things. First the set() - set() but the probleme is that I get good with r1 and r2 with img2. So I tried to change var.get() : [can.image] to var.get() : [RandomImage] because the programs return some complicated "tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0*0000...." but my code don't actualize the fact that I change image when I click on b1. I don' know what I can do. I'm stuck here.
I'm a beginner and I think I started with a too much complicated project. However I want to understand the problem here.
Sorry If my code is Awfull.

```
from tkinter import * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
import random
import pandas 

imagelist = ['C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\ECG Learner\\ecg.png','C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\ECG Learner\\img2.png']
textlist = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

good_answer = {"1" : ['C:\\Users\\Noé\\Desktop\\ECG Learner\\ecg.png'],"2":['C:\\Users\\Noé\\Desktop\\ECG Learner\\img2.png']}

def open_fenetre2 () :
    fenetre2 = Tk()

def callback () :
    textlist = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    can.delete("all")
    RandomImage = random.choice(imagelist)  
    im = (RandomImage)
    img=PhotoImage(file=im)
    can.configure(width=img.width(), height=img.height())
    can.create_image(img.width()/2,img.height()/2,image=img)
    can.image =img
    n1 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
    RandomText1 =textlist[n1]
    del(textlist[n1])
    n2 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
    RandomText2 = textlist[n2]
    del(textlist[n2])
    n3 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
    RandomText3 =textlist[n3]
    del(textlist[n3])
    n4 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
    RandomText4 = textlist[n4]
    del(textlist[n4])

    r1.config(text=RandomText1)
    r2.config(text=RandomText2)
    r3.config(text=RandomText3)
    r4.config(text=RandomText4)


def selected ():
    print(var.get())

def verification () :
    resultat = { var.get() : [can.image]}
    print(resultat)
    diff = set(resultat)- set(good_answer)
    print(diff)
    if diff == set() :
        print("vrai")
        true.config(bg = "green")
        false.config(bg="white")
    else :
        print("faux")
        false.config(bg = "red")
        true.config(bg="white")
        




n1 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
RandomText1 =textlist[n1]
del(textlist[n1])
n2 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
RandomText2 = textlist[n2]
del(textlist[n2])
n3 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
RandomText3 =textlist[n3]
del(textlist[n3])
n4 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
RandomText4 = textlist[n4]
del(textlist[n4])

fenetre = Tk()
fenetre.title("ECG Learner")
fenetre.config(bg="white")
fenetre.geometry("500x500")
fenetre.minsize(200,200)

can = Canvas(fenetre)
can.pack()

RandomImage = random.choice(imagelist)  
im = (RandomImage)
img=PhotoImage(file=im)
can.configure(width=img.width(), height=img.height())
can.create_image(img.width()/2,img.height()/2,image=img)
can.image =img

can2 = Canvas(fenetre)
can2.pack(anchor ="s")


menu1 = Menu(fenetre)
menu1.add_cascade(label ="fichier")
menu1.add_cascade(label ="option")
menu1.add_cascade(label ="aide")
fenetre.config(menu = menu1)


cadre1 = Frame(fenetre)
cadre1.pack()

var = StringVar()


b1 = Button (cadre1, text = 'Next ECG', command=callback)
b1.pack()

b2 = Button (cadre1, text = 'Quitter', command= fenetre.destroy)
b2.pack()

b3 = Button (fenetre, text ="Valider", command= verification)
b3.pack()


r1 = Radiobutton(can2, text = RandomText1, variable = var, value = "1", command = selected)
r1.pack()
r2 = Radiobutton(can2, text = RandomText2, variable = var, value = "2", command = selected)
r2.pack()
r3 = Radiobutton(can2, text = RandomText3, variable = var, value = "3",  command = selected)
r3.pack()
r4 = Radiobutton(can2, text = RandomText4, variable = var, value = "4",  command = selected)
r4.pack()


true = Label(fenetre, text = "Vrai", font =("Courier", 30))
true.pack()
false = Label(fenetre, text = "Faux", font =("Courier", 30))
false.pack()


fenetre.mainloop()
```

Thanks for your time !!!

Comment: Why are you duplicated `textlist = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]`?

Comment: In the first place, I delete things from my list with del() to avoid repetition. I think if I don't duplicate the list there will be nothing to take inside.

Comment: On line 8 and 14

Comment: indeed maybe on line 8 it is useless

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare the answer `good_answer[var.get()][0]` with a random selection `can.image.cget("file")`, not two dictionaries.

```
from tkinter import *
import random


imagelist = ['C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\ECG Learner\\ecg.png','C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\ECG Learner\\img2.png']
textlist = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

good_answer = {"1": ['C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\ECG Learner\\ecg.png'],
               "2": ['C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\ECG Learner\\img2.png'],
               "3": [""],
          "4": [""]}


def open_fenetre2():
    fenetre2 = Tk()


def callback():
    textlist = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    can.delete("all")
    RandomImage = random.choice(imagelist)
    im = (RandomImage)
    img = PhotoImage(file=im)
    can.configure(width=img.width(), height=img.height())
    can.create_image(img.width() / 2, img.height() / 2, image=img)
    can.image = img
    n1 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
    RandomText1 = textlist[n1]
    del (textlist[n1])
    n2 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
    RandomText2 = textlist[n2]
    del (textlist[n2])
    n3 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
    RandomText3 = textlist[n3]
    del (textlist[n3])
    n4 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
    RandomText4 = textlist[n4]
    del (textlist[n4])

    r1.config(text=RandomText1)
    r2.config(text=RandomText2)
    r3.config(text=RandomText3)
    r4.config(text=RandomText4)


def selected():
    print(var.get())


def verification():
    resultat = can.image.cget("file")
    print(resultat)
    choice = good_answer[var.get()][0]
    print(choice)
    if resultat == choice:
        print("vrai")
        true.config(bg="green")
        false.config(bg="white")
    else:
        print("faux")
        false.config(bg="red")
        true.config(bg="white")


n1 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
RandomText1 = textlist[n1]
del (textlist[n1])
n2 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
RandomText2 = textlist[n2]
del (textlist[n2])
n3 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
RandomText3 = textlist[n3]
del (textlist[n3])
n4 = random.randrange(len(textlist))
RandomText4 = textlist[n4]
del (textlist[n4])

fenetre = Tk()
fenetre.title("ECG Learner")
fenetre.config(bg="white")
fenetre.geometry("500x500")
fenetre.minsize(200, 200)

can = Canvas(fenetre)
can.pack()

RandomImage = random.choice(imagelist)
im = (RandomImage)
img = PhotoImage(file=im)
can.configure(width=img.width(), height=img.height())
can.create_image(img.width() / 2, img.height() / 2, image=img)
can.image = img

can2 = Canvas(fenetre)
can2.pack(anchor="s")

menu1 = Menu(fenetre)
menu1.add_cascade(label="fichier")
menu1.add_cascade(label="option")
menu1.add_cascade(label="aide")
fenetre.config(menu=menu1)

cadre1 = Frame(fenetre)
cadre1.pack()

var = StringVar()

b1 = Button(cadre1, text='Next ECG', command=callback)
b1.pack()

b2 = Button(cadre1, text='Quitter', command=fenetre.destroy)
b2.pack()

b3 = Button(fenetre, text="Valider", command=verification)
b3.pack()

r1 = Radiobutton(can2, text=RandomText1, variable=var, value="1", command=selected)
r1.pack()
r2 = Radiobutton(can2, text=RandomText2, variable=var, value="2", command=selected)
r2.pack()
r3 = Radiobutton(can2, text=RandomText3, variable=var, value="3", command=selected)
r3.pack()
r4 = Radiobutton(can2, text=RandomText4, variable=var, value="4", command=selected)
r4.pack()

true = Label(fenetre, text="Vrai", font=("Courier", 30))
true.pack()
false = Label(fenetre, text="Faux", font=("Courier", 30))
false.pack()

fenetre.mainloop()
```